# Text areas disappearing in for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.frames; i++)
                {
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-12">
            Pins Hit
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Pins, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Pins", maxlength = 200 })
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pins)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-12 text-left ">
            Score
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Score, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Score", maxlength = 200 })

        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Score)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-12">
            Frame Number
        </div>
            <div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.frames, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = 200 })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.frames)
            </div>
    </div>
    }
```

I am experiencing an odd issue. When I generate this for loop, and start the debug process, everything contained within does not show up on the page. The intention of this loop is to iterate the frames of a bowling game.

Comment: And you're sure `Model.frames` is greater than zero?

Comment: @KirkWoll, I will check that now, Should I Initialize the variable in the Controller?

Comment: @Joshua, you need to pass model from controller.

Comment: @Joshua if `frames` is part of the model, it should have some value, which you would have defined somewhere.

Comment: Yes, since you are clearly expecting it to not be zero, you will have to populate your model in your controller so the data is in a state your view expects.

Comment: don't you need the @ sign before the for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your model, but from what I can infer from your code you probably want to display a set of frames (10, yes?) with the current frame nr, the pins that are down and the current score.

Simplified, that would boil down to something like this:

```
public class Frame
{
    public int FrameNr { get; set; }
    public int Pins { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }

}

public class FrameController : Controller
{
    //...

    // GET: Frames
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //replace this with your actual data from the database
        var vm = new List<Frame>
        {
            new Models.Frame { FrameNr = 1, Pins = 5, Score = 5},
            new Models.Frame { FrameNr = 2, Pins = 6, Score = 5},
            new Models.Frame { FrameNr = 3, Pins = 7, Score = 5},
            new Models.Frame { FrameNr = 5, Pins = 8, Score = 5},
            new Models.Frame { FrameNr = 9, Pins = 9, Score = 5},
            new Models.Frame { FrameNr = 12, Pins = 10, Score = 5},
        };
        //pass data to view
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

In your view you can now iterate over your collection of frames:

```
@model IEnumerable<namespace.Models.Frame>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FrameNr)
}
```